# XCode: Split one long comment into multiple lines with fixed number of characters

Tags: xcode, comments

Single line comments in XCode word wrap by default. Is there any way to force comments to span multiple lines

NOT

```
// So that really long comments that would not normally be split across multiple lines like this one, which look really annoying in git commit history or other editors which do not text wrap like the one on stack overflow . . . .
```

BUT

```
// So that really long comments
// end up split across multiple 
// lines like this?
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode Preferences -> Text Editing -> Indentation (clickable text) and deselect Line wrapping

Comment: Does not solve word wrap issue as it does not insert return chars.